# how to implement simple Compare And Swap in C++ for shared counter

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to learn concurrency without locks. Thus I am trying to implement simple Compare and Swap(cas) for shared variable counter.I tried to create 10 threads and want to increase the counter value by each thread by 1 using CAS. since CAS store the old value and compare with the current value and update only if the values are unchanged. looking[here] I tried to implement the CAS, but couldn't get it right. How to implement CAS for counter shared variable in c++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <atomic>



std::atomic<int> count = 0;
std::mutex n_mutux;

void increase_counter(int i)
{
    int old_value = count.load() ;
    while (!count.compare_exchange_weak(old_value, old_value +1))
    {
    }



}
int main() {

    int thread_num =10;
    std::thread t[thread_num];
    for(int i=0;i<thread_num;i++)
    {
        t[i]=std::thread((increase_counter),i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<thread_num;i++)
    {
        t[i].join();
    }
   std::cout<<count;
}
```

Comment: You should update old_value in your while loop

Comment: What are those parentheses for, in `std::thread((increase_counter), i)`?

Comment: @FlorianM. I am trying to update with oldvalue +1.and is initialization of count as atomic shared variable correct??

Comment: @DeanSeo increase_counter is a function call by each thread with i in case the thread id is required.

Comment: The code *seems* to be correct. What is a problem? Do you get unexpected output from `std::cout<<count;`? Or what?

Comment: within the while loop shouldn't you set the old value to count ?

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is correct.

Another way is to use the increment, see [`std::atomic::operator++()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) or [`fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add). These two do not require a busy waiting loop.

There is a compiler error with the initialization of `std::atomic<int> count = 0`. Fix:

```
std::atomic<int> count{0};
```

And a slightly more efficient CAS is:

```
void increase_counter(int i) {
    int old_value = count.load() ;
    while(!count.compare_exchange_weak(old_value, old_value + 1,
                                       std::memory_order_release,
                                       std::memory_order_relaxed)) 
        _mm_pause();
}
```

[Pause Intrinsic](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524249):

> The `pause` intrinsic is used in spin-wait loops with the processors implementing dynamic execution (especially out-of-order execution). In the spin-wait loop, the `pause` intrinsic improves the speed at which the code detects the release of the lock and provides especially significant performance gain.
>
> The execution of the next instruction is delayed for an implementation-specific amount of time. The `pause` instruction does not modify the architectural state. For dynamic scheduling, the `pause` instruction reduces the penalty of exiting from the spin-loop.

See [Benefitting Power and Performance Sleep Loops](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops) for more details and benchmarks.