# How does c++ compose atomic operations?

Tags: c++, atomic

C++ atomic's are good thing, my question is only how they compose together.

```
    uint64_t lpp = (place_st++ == A-1)? place_st.exchange(0) : place_st.load();

    ...
    atomic<uint64_t> place_st;
    ...
```

So, is there any guarantee that these operations will be executed ONLY one by one,like in transactional memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there won't be any guarantee of that, making the code unsafe (one thread might see a value greater than `A`, and an increment might be 'lost' by a `place_st.exchange(0)`.

The easiest thing to do here might be to just consider `place_st` as "unwrapped", and manually do `uint64_t lpp = place_st++ % A` to get the "wrapped" version. Beyond that, to get this sort of behavior you'd basically need compare-and-swap in a loop (see [how to implement simple Compare And Swap in C++ for shared counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802217/how-to-implement-simple-compare-and-swap-in-c-for-shared-counter)), rather than the atomic increment, to get the increment and wrapping to behave atomically. Since you're only operating on a single variable, you can use CAS to emulate the transactional memory approach you were considering.

Answer (score 9):

Atomic operations only promise atomicity (and relative ordering given the right parameters): the inability for other operations on different threads to interfere with their operations. Two operations which are both atomic are still *two operations*, so stuff can happen in-between them.